# Best way to send location data to Azure Mobile Services using a .NET Backend

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm new to Azure Mobile Services, and Entity Framework. So my apologies if this is a rather newbie question... but I've spent a few hours thinking about it without coming to a good conclusion.

I want to store some location data in a `DbGeography` class in my SQL Database. I've created the code, using code-first migration in C#. Below is the entire class

```
public class Place : EntityData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public DbGeography Coordinates{ get; set; }
}
```

So the server side code is complete, along with the "standard" controller.

However, it is getting my location data to this `DbGeography` object I am struggling with. This is my current client side class:

```
public class Place 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "location")]
    public string Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

To me, it wouldn't make sense to use a `DbGeography` object on the client side... as it doesn't interact with the database. Therefore I would either like to use a complex type, such as `Point` or a primative such as `string` and then "convert" this information on the server side. Probably in the controller.

My question is, how would I go about doing this? Or is my thought process completely wrong in terms of how I am using Azure Mobile Services?

Thanks.

Danny

Comment: I would use exactly the same data structure in client as you have in database and mobile service. At least with WP8 apps life is a lot more easier if you do so, certain methods require this if you want to read/write data from mobile service.

Comment: Don't you think importing the EntityFramework dll's is a bit OTT for this one type though? Seems weird to be using DB types client side...

Comment: Well one option is to discard `DbGeography` and store only those elements you need. Like longitude and latitude as `double`. I ran into a lot of trouble when I tried to consume data via mobile service when client class didn't match db tables.

Comment: I discovered in the end that ultimately it was easier to switch to the node.js backend. This made taking the request and entering it into the db as a dbgeography much easier. Theres even a tutorial: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-sample-end-to-5d9ee245